# MySQL Workbench Trigger Syntax

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am working with MySQL workbench and trying to create a simple trigger statement:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER 
TRIGGER `School_database`.`Faculty_BEFORE_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `Faculty` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (inserted.salary < 25000 OR inserted.salary > 85000) 
  THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'Faculty salary must be between $25,000 and $85,000');
    END IF;
END;
```

For some reason, I get the error at raise_application_error: "Syntax error: missing colon"

Would anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? I'm not sure why I'm getting that error since I have a colon at the end of the function call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

raise_application_error is an Oracle thing, it does not exist in mysql. Therefore mysql interprets it as a user variable name and expects you to assign it a value with the := operator, hence the error message about the misding colon.

In mysql use the [signal command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/signal.html) to raise an exception.

You will probably have to take a look at the delimiter command as well.